# Wordpress navigation not showing properly?

Tags: wordpress

My website http://bamboobot.com/ shows up fine on the home page but on my marketing services and pricing pages the navigation doesn't show up properly!?

However when I am logged in it shows up fine. Why is this?????

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling each plugin one by one. Looking through the source-code, there seems to be some anomalies occurring between pages with CSS showing on some and not others.

I have a feeling it may be something to do with a minification plugin (WPFC-Minified) as your code shows an include of the minified CSS on the index but not on the marketing services page.

You also have a problem of having CSS coded into the actual header.php file and not within a CSS file, i would recommend getting that fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Many `Wordpress` plugins will cache the backend like the front end. Check to see if you are using a caching plugin or even something like `Cloudflare`. Clear the cache and you should be good to go.